# Coq : notation not printed

Tags: coq, coqide

I defined an inductive type, minimal example below. I would like to use notations, like ~ or =. The syntax is recognized, but not printed in the goals of the top right panel.

Example:

```
Inductive num : Set :=
  | O : num
  | S : num -> num.

Theorem test (n : num) : ~ (S n) = O.
```

The panel says:

```
1 subgoal
n : num
______________________________________(1/1)
not (@eq num (S n) O)
```

While I expect:

```
1 subgoal
n : num
______________________________________(1/1)
~ (S n) = O
```

I tried to redefine = like this, without success:

```
Notation "x = y" := (@eq num x y) (at level 70).
```

Or define a new symbol, without success either:

```
Notation "x =n y" := (@eq num x y) (at level 50).
Theorem test (n : num) : ~ (S n) =n O.
```

Is it a settings issue? I'm using CoqIde 8.7.2 on Mac.

Comment: It may be you have `Set Printing All.` somewhere. Or `Unset Printing Notations.` + a bunch of other commands changing printing.

Comment: Finally I updated to the latest CoqIde version (8.8.2) and the problem is solved. Probably a bug.